# jQuery clear DOM previously loaded scripts

Tags: jquery, dom, load

Good day people, I am working on a project where i load pages into divs using jQuery, and each page has its own jQuery scripts, my problem is that the previously loaded scripts are not clearing from DOM and that creates a bigger problem for my project.

For example, I have a set of timers in one page where it auto saves data but when I change the page the timers are still running and messing up the contents.

I manage changing pages like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('li').click(function (event) {

      $('.progressbarone').hide();
      var theitem = this.id;
      //isf ajax to load with addon
      var thefile = "isf_ajax.php?addon="+this.id;
      var progress = '<span class="progressbarone"><img src="'
         + THEMEURL
         + '/gfx/images/progessbar1.gif" width="20" height="16" /></span>';

      // pre actions
      $('.'+ theitem +'_item')
         .append(progress)
         .children(':last')
         .hide()
         .fadeIn(1000);
      $('li').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');

      // load the page
      $('#childpage').remove();
      $('#officetable').html('<div id="childpage">loading</div>');
      $('#childpage').load(thefile, function() {

         // after load actions
         $('.progressbarone').fadeOut(2000);
      });
   });
});
```

As you can see I have two divs, one is called office table that handles the childpage and childpage has the contents for changed pages. however as you can see I have used the remove(); function as well and after that I placed the childpage to officetable and posted the contents of the file, but still it doesn't remove my previously loaded scripts.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you append your scripts to the page, those are run. Although you remove the scripts tags from the DOM, the variables will remain. By that I mean timers, functions, any kind of variable declared in your code.

So you might want to clear the previous state which is not desired anymore.

```
function doTheCleanup(){
    clearTimeout(globalTimerVariable);
    delete someGloablVar;
    //and so on
}
```

Comment: i am going give this a try, thanks i will let you know the result.

Comment: it worked out with a little modification thank you i am also new to SOF is there anyother rating system so i can rate you buddy.

Comment: @user997057 Glad it helped you out! if you have several timers or variables, I recommend to keep them organized (i.e. in an object, etc.).

Comment: actualy i had only one timer to save the data of tinymce editor so what i did actually i completely removed the timer (however your solution was working when i tested it) and i put up a save it now button to save the contents on a click event while there i also installed a mce plugin that autosaves data after x number of seconds and i set to save it for 24 hours after each 60 seconds. i guess thats what i want. instead of executing ajax -> sql every 60 seconds while there could be no more changes on editor to process extra waste of energy for mysql and ajax right?

Answer (score 1):

If your scripts have already executed removing the DOM elements are not going to get rid of them. Go to any page with JavaScript, open up firebug or console and type $("script").remove(). Everything keeps running.

Here are some tips:

1. Don't re-include your script with every ajax call.
2. If you
   have    events that need handling use jQuery.live()
3. Only set any
   timers    once, not on every ajax call.

It sounds like you're building a single page web-app, you may want to look at using something like [backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) to organize your code and help you follow some better patterns. check out this tutorial:

http://addyosmani.com/blog/building-spas-jquerys-best-friends/

Best of luck

Comment: thats right i am building a SPWP so far i don't have any complains except this timer thingy. i am using jquery live for modules and i don't re-include the script on every jquery call. i am too far finishing this project so i can't go back to step 0 and start using backbone.js although its a nice thingy i wish i had seen it before starting this project.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the problem! Where are you doing your timers? As the other poster said you can save the results of setInterval like this. var timer = setInterval(myFunction(){}); And assuming that variable is in scope you can later call clearInterval(timer). best of luck!

Comment: yes i am going to do it like he suggested i am new to jquery and whole javascript i am actually a php-mysql expert but the SPWP i am developing is turning out to be real awesome i might send you a demo link when its done.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you removed the progress bar span? Also, you might consider using $.deferred -> .done

Comment: this will not stop previously loaded scripts, i have tried it, i suppose its only used to callback other function or set of functions after an action is actually successfully executed