# jQuery dialog with load doesnt clean up after itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I'm pretty sure this was somewhere discussed, but I cant seem to find it anywhere. I would really appreciate if anyone could point me to the right direction.

I have setup a dialog which opens and closes just fine. I need to load dynamic content in it and so Im using this:

```
$('#dialog').load("somepage.php?document=1");
```

This load up correctly and everything works pretty much fine except the fact that once I close the dialog and then open it with some different query string (e.g. with document=2) I can see that there are still contents of document=1 loaded in DOM.

This causes issue when there is  javascript function in the Loaded page because than it gets executed twice. (well the number of times I load documents so its pretty much unusable).

I have tried clearing the dialog:

```
$('#dialog').html("")
```

But that didnt help much.

Does anyone have any idea what could help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of just closing the dialog, destroy it:

```
$('#dialog').dialog("destroy");
```

That should clear the dialog back to its initial state:

https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-destroy

Comment: Thank you, however that didnt really help. I have cleared, destroyed the dialog and then binded it again, but it still seems like the javascript function is still present somewhere, however Im not able to locate it with firebug ./

Comment: Ah, now I see what you are doing - loading full page contents into the target div, and those target pages have scripts baked into them. My suggestion is that you change the target pages and load the scripts that they contain separately. There is no need to load them more than once, it wastes bandwidth and causes all kinds of issues. Alternately, if you can't change those pages, see this discussion on clearing them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779313/jquery-clear-dom-previously-loaded-scripts.

Comment: Hey, thats exactly right. I can see a lot of scripts still loaded in FireBug even though the DOM for the div is destroyed, empty or whatever. The scripts remain there. I will take a look at the question you posted! Thank you for taking the time, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just load `part` of a page, you can always do the following: Let's say I want a specific `div` only.

```
$('#dialog').load("somepage.php?document=1 #myDiv");
```

Furthermore, I don't know what you're closing your `#dialog` with, but if it was something with an id of myButton, you'd do:

```
$(document).on("click", "#myButton", function(e) {
    // To keep div within DOM and empty
    $("#dialog").empty();
    // To get rid of div (you would have to re-append #dialog every time)
    $("#dialog").remove();
});
```

All this being said, `.load()` doesn't actually execute any scripts from your loaded page. If you were to use `$.post()` or `$.get()`, you could strip out the `<script>` tags yourself.

Best of luck!